# How to dynamically push new elements into a list

Tags: java, android, listview

I work to a project where I need to add various elements to a list.

The reason to do that is that I use multiple spinners with various abbreviations inside them and after selecting values from that spinners the user need to see a list with all the explications.

The problem is that my elements are not populated one under another but they come one after the precedent in line.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks in advance for all your help.
Here is what i have already do:

```
  String a = "a";
  String b = "b";

  List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
  data.add(a+" "+b);
  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
  lista.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: What do you mean? If you're trying to simply add in multiple elements to a list just do data.add(a); then data.add(b);

Comment: please be more clear as to what you're trying to achieve, and why it's not working as expected. There are very clever people here, but we're not mind readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `adapter.add( "New element" );` it will udpate the list,

If you want to add multiple element or list of element you can use `adapter.addAll(list)`

Comment: Thanks, this do the job for me.

Answer (score 2):

The class `List<T>` in Java works in a way that you can add new elements, quite easy by using `myList.add(el);`, and it also works dynamically. When the `List` gets filled up, Java automatically resizes the list with 2x the size, so you can continue adding elements to it, just by using the `add()` method. It will kind of stop working only if you run out of memory.

Hope this helps!